# How to make Material UI Temporary Drawer button as icon instead of text?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI to create a navigation bar with Temporary Drawer. When the user clicks on the hamburger menu icon, I want the menu to fade-in to the screen and slide from the right.

Basically, all the functionality works, except only the button named 'RIGHT' works instead of the hamburger icon I have created beside it..

I have tried removing 'right' and replace it with the icon, but when I do that the menu comes out from left-top...

[image]

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { AppBar, IconButton, Toolbar, Typography, Collapse } from '@material-ui/core';
import SortIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Sort';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import { Link as Scroll } from 'react-scroll'

import clsx from 'clsx';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';



const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: "100vh",
        fontFamily: "Roboto",
    },
    appbar: {
        background: "none",
    },
    appbarWrapper: {
        width: "80%",
        margin: "0 auto"
    },
    appbarTitle: {

        fontSize: "2rem",

        flexGrow: '1',
    },
    icon: {
        color: '#fff',
        fontSize: "2rem",
    },
    colorText: {
        color: "#5AFF3D",
    },
    container: {
        textAlign: "center",
    },
    title: {
        color: "#fff",
        fontSize: "4.5rem",
    },
    goDown: {
        color: '#5AFF3D',
        fontSize: '4rem',
    },
    list: { //NEW
        width: 250,
    },
    fullList: {
        width: 'auto',
    },
}));

export default function Header() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        setChecked(true);
    }, [])

    // NEW

    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        right: false,
    });

    const toggleDrawer = (anchor, open) => (event) => {
        if (event.type === 'keydown' && (event.key === 'Tab' || event.key === 'Shift')) {
            return;
        }

        setState({ ...state, [anchor]: open });
    };

    const list = (anchor) => (
        <div
            className={clsx(classes.list, {
                [classes.fullList]: anchor === 'top' || anchor === 'bottom',
            })}
            role="presentation"
            onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
            onKeyDown={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
        >
            <List>
                {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
                    <ListItem button key={text}>
                        <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText primary={text} />
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
            </List>
            <Divider />
            <List>
                {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
                    <ListItem button key={text}>
                        <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText primary={text} />
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
            </List>
        </div>
    );


    /*
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

    const handleClick = (event) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
    };
    */

    return (
        <div className={classes.root} id="header">
            <AppBar className={classes.appbar} elevation={0}>
                <Toolbar className={classes.appbarWrapper}>
                    <h1 className={classes.appbarTitle}>
                        We<span className={classes.colorText}>cycle</span>
                    </h1>
                    <IconButton>
                        <SortIcon className={classes.icon} /*onClick={handleClick} aria-control="fade-menu" aria-haspopup="true"*/ />

                        
                        {['right'].map((anchor) => (
                            <React.Fragment key={anchor}>
                                <Button onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, true)}>{anchor}</Button>
                                <Drawer anchor={anchor} open={state[anchor]} onClose={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}>
                                    {list(anchor)}
                                </Drawer>
                            </React.Fragment>
                        ))}
                    </IconButton>



                    {/* <Menu
                        id="fade-menu"
                        anchorEl={anchorEl}
                        keepMounted
                        open={open}
                        onClose={handleClose}
                        TransitionComponent={Fade}
                    >
                        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
                    </Menu> */}

                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>

            <Collapse
                in={checked} {...(checked ? { timeout: 1000 } : {})}
                collapsedHeight={50}
            >
                <div className={classes.container}>
                    <h1 className={classes.title}>
                        Meet the <br /> <span className={classes.colorText}>Team </span>
                    </h1>
                    <Scroll to="place-to-visit" smooth={true}>
                        <IconButton>
                            <ExpandMoreIcon className={classes.goDown} />
                        </IconButton>
                    </Scroll>
                </div>
            </Collapse>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made your code work for what you need and left some comments inside. I don't know what you ideally want to make, but don't copy all the code from the MUI example which you might not fully understand.

```
const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(false);
// const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setAnchorEl(true);
};

const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(false);
};
```

Above is used to control the state of Drawer.

Following is the code that you can just copy.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { AppBar, IconButton, Toolbar, Typography, Collapse } from '@material-ui/core';
import SortIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Sort';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import { Link as Scroll } from 'react-scroll'

import clsx from 'clsx';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';



const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: "100vh",
        fontFamily: "Roboto",
    },
    appbar: {
        background: "none",
    },
    appbarWrapper: {
        width: "80%",
        margin: "0 auto"
    },
    appbarTitle: {

        fontSize: "2rem",

        flexGrow: '1',
    },
    icon: {
        color: '#fff',
        fontSize: "2rem",
    },
    colorText: {
        color: "#5AFF3D",
    },
    container: {
        textAlign: "center",
    },
    title: {
        color: "#fff",
        fontSize: "4.5rem",
    },
    goDown: {
        color: '#5AFF3D',
        fontSize: '4rem',
    },
    list: { //NEW
        width: 250,
    },
    fullList: {
        width: 'auto',
    },
}));

export default function Header() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        setChecked(true);
    }, [])

    // NEW

    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        right: false,
    });

    const toggleDrawer = (anchor, open) => (event) => {
        if (event.type === 'keydown' && (event.key === 'Tab' || event.key === 'Shift')) {
            return;
        }

        setState({ ...state, [anchor]: open });
    };

    const list = (anchor) => (
        <div
            className={clsx(classes.list, {
                [classes.fullList]: anchor === 'top' || anchor === 'bottom',
            })}
            role="presentation"
            onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
            onKeyDown={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
        >
            <List>
                {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
                    <ListItem button key={text}>
                        <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText primary={text} />
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
            </List>
            <Divider />
            <List>
                {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
                    <ListItem button key={text}>
                        <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText primary={text} />
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
            </List>
        </div>
    );



    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(false);
    // const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

    const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
        setAnchorEl(true);
    };

    const handleDrawerClose = () => {
        setAnchorEl(false);
    };


    return (
        <div className={classes.root} id="header">
            <AppBar className={classes.appbar} elevation={0}>
                <Toolbar className={classes.appbarWrapper}>
                    <h1 className={classes.appbarTitle}>
                        We<span className={classes.colorText}>cycle</span>
                    </h1>

                    {/* You Don't need the map here unless you want many button to toggle one Drawer,
                    like the example on https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/.
                    and the point here for your question is to move the onClick to IconButton, and you may
                    not want the button inside IconButton, since it is a button already,
                    the inside button would make it a little ugly */}
                    <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerOpen} onClose={handleDrawerClose}>
                        <SortIcon className={classes.icon} /*onClick={handleClick} aria-control="fade-menu" aria-haspopup="true"*/ />
                        RIGHT{/* delete the text here if you don't need */}                        
                    </IconButton>
                    <Drawer anchor='right' open={anchorEl} onClose={handleDrawerClose}>
                        {list('right')}
                    </Drawer>

                    {/* <Menu
                        id="fade-menu"
                        anchorEl={anchorEl}
                        keepMounted
                        open={open}
                        onClose={handleClose}
                        TransitionComponent={Fade}
                    >
                        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
                    </Menu> */}

                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>

            <Collapse
                in={checked} {...(checked ? { timeout: 1000 } : {})}
                collapsedHeight={50}
            >
                <div className={classes.container}>
                    <h1 className={classes.title}>
                        Meet the <br /> <span className={classes.colorText}>Team </span>
                    </h1>
                    <Scroll to="place-to-visit" smooth={true}>
                        <IconButton>
                            <ExpandMoreIcon className={classes.goDown} />
                        </IconButton>
                    </Scroll>
                </div>
            </Collapse>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Recomandation: since you have `import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'`, you may not use `React.useState()` but use `useState()` directly.